# How do I make a stackview at the top of a scrollview?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried the instructions from http://fuckingscrollviewautolayout.com/ to no avail; I have gotten everything to work but the top constraint is not behaving as expected. It says it's 0, but there's clearly a very non-zero line forcing my stackview inside the scrollview to be greatly below the top of the scrollview.

Comment: can you elaborate what happens ?

Comment: There's a vertical constraint between the top of the stackview and the top of the scrollview. It says "0" but on the UI it's clearly very non-zero, and in the simulator is also non-zero. I've tried deleting other constraints to no avail.

Comment: i even tried "align: top edges" selecting both of them. This just creates another constraint which is identical to the existing constraint (and behavior is same as before). For that matter, this segues into my next question: WHY does apple allow exact duplicate constraints to clutter up the project?

Comment: i cant getting you... can you share your screenshot ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByBotxOxRJkDV3NNNTYzZWRycjg

Comment: give height and width to stackview to solve constraint error. it will be zero while you have run app in simulator or device.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the issue. And I don't want to give explicit height to stackview because the whole point of scrollview is that the height can vary

Comment: yes but you need to give according constraint to stackview because scrollview will calculates height as per content size.

Comment: I read this: "The scroll view needs to be pinned to the leading and trailing margins, with a space of zero. It should also be pinned to the top and bottom of the root view (not the layout guides - you’ll need to hold alt down while choosing constraints to get this instead)." My scrollview is clearly constrained to the layout "guide' but I cant figure out how to "hold alt down" to get it to do the other thing!

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, I finally figured it out after extensive research. I think it was because of navigation bar, but it really was extreme complicatedness/obscurity of Apple, no way to spin it otherwise.

First I read on http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2017/01/09/scrollviews-and-stack-views/ that "The scroll view needs to be pinned to the leading and trailing margins, with a space of zero. It should also be pinned to the top and bottom of the root view (not the layout guides - you’ll need to hold alt down while choosing constraints to get this instead)." Okay, but I couldn't figure out how to hold alt down to get these results.

Finally, I dragged the scroll view all the way to the top of the entire UI preview (PAST the navigation bar). Then, I deleted the "top" constraint of the scrollview. Then, I added another constraint that the top constraint of the scrollview should be zero. Magically, this allowed me to set the top of the scrollview to the "top" rather than the "guide layout top" and this fixed my issue.